# The following returns a NoSuchElementException, can you help me identify the mistake in the xpath syntax?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't find the error with my xpath element locator

Login using automated testing tool Selenium webdriver

```
 driver.findElement(By.className("btn-primary")).click();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-labelledby='vaadin-text-field-label-19']")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-labelledby='vaadin-text-field-label-19']")).sendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("12345678");
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn-block")).click();
```

Comment: Please share the HTML code ?

Comment: <input part="value" tabindex="0" required="" aria-required="" placeholder="Enter email address" aria-labelledby="vaadin-text-field-label-21" invalid="" aria-invalid="">

Comment: Always put all the relevant info to answering the question in the question itself, rather than in the comments. This will make it easier for future readers to get all the necessary info without having to read all the comments. Just edit the question, add the details there, and then message the other use with @<username> to let them know that you've made the requested changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following `xpath` to enter details.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://jbm4u.com/jupiter/#/signin");
        driver.findElement(By.className("btn-primary")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card']//vaadin-text-field[@placeholder='Enter email address']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card']//vaadin-text-field[@placeholder='Enter email address']")).sendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card']//vaadin-password-field[@placeholder='Enter Password']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card']//vaadin-password-field[@placeholder='Enter Password']")).sendKeys("12345678");

    }
```

**Browser Snapshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter email address']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter email address']")).sendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
```

Please avoid referring to attributes which has dynamic indexing in your example(vaadin-text-field-label-21) 21 is dynamically generated which tend to change for every time when you refresh or for a new session.

Comment: No, i have tried it this way as well ,it returns the same exception:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@placeholder='Enter email address']"}

Comment: Error you are receiving at button click or for the input?

Comment: For both click and input, the same exception, i think it is unable to find the element itself

Comment: Can you please post the html which you are working at and also give a try with this css selector once 
Can you please try with this CSS selector

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder=\"Enter email address\"]"))

Comment: http://jbm4u.com/jupiter/#/signin, this is the link, i have tried with css selector as well

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to fill in the email address you need this selector:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("vaadin-text-field[placeholder='Enter email address']")).sendKeys("test@email.com")`

The password field is:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("vaadin-password-field[placeholder='Enter Password']")).sendKeys("dwedewdw")`

And the submit button:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class*='btn-block']")).click()`

Try and avoid Xpath whenever possible, it's too flakey. I've tested the above selectors myself.